# Trying to position elements does not work

Tags: css, html, css-float

I would like to position 5 column blocks,each containing text in a row.I have tried to create a wrapper class which has a width of 1600px,a padding of 30px to the left and the right and two classes that will align content to the left and the right respectively,each of these classes are in nested divs within the wrapper class.I gave each div a width of 300px and a height of 300px,the first four divs align next to each other while the last one goes below and to the right.The CSS and HTML is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/Qk4uW/1/).

## EDIT:

The major issue got fixed when:

```
.wrapper
{
    width:1600px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

But this seems to exceed the screen resolution needing me to scroll horizontally to view all the content,how do I deal with different screen resolutions?

Comment: you wrote `css` for `.content-right` but where is your `HTML` code?

Comment: @ars29 check out the last div inside the wrapper...would it work if it were outside the wrapper.

Comment: I think, no need to add `.content-right` in CSS or HTML, `.content-left` is fine.

Comment: its always a good practice to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for such type of question, it helps other to answer the question easily.

Comment: @ars29 will keep that in mind,will also modify the question to link to a fiddle instead of just showing raw code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to give `width:1600px;`

```
.wrapper
{
    width:1600px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sKsZN/

Comment: Thanks,this worked,I used `content-left` to position it,it is not working with content-right(there is a space between the left positioned and the right positioned item),now it looks like I exceeded the screen resolution,how do I manage this issue?

Comment: reduce the width of each div

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float:left` and `display:inline-block` for all the column `<div>`. Also make sure that the total `width` of those column don't exceed to `.wrapper`'s `width`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `float:left` for your `.content-right` class. http://jsfiddle.net/sDyC5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper element css width property has set to wrong value. You must set the properly unit (px|%|em|ex). And also display: inline-block and float propeties should not use together.